# Interaction with SearchView in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I'm using the SearchView widget in ActionbarSherlock as a follows:

**File.java**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.MenuSearch).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

**File.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/MenuSearch" android:title="@string/Bs"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" >
</item>

</menu>
```

In my application I get to show the search icon and select it unfolds the search box for the widget, but when I write any search I do not know how to interact with the widget SearchView to launch a new activity and show a series of results.

With the command `searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);` appears a icon similar to 'play' and I suppose it is for just that, but I do not know how to interact with it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Some response please.

Answer (score 1):

Set a QueryTextListner.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String key) {
    //After you press Search/Enter control comes here with entered text in "key"
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String key) {
    //Each time you enter/modify a charcter, control comes here with entered text in "key"
    return true;
  }
});
```